# An outline of proving Gelfand-Neimark Theorem for Commutative $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, gelfand-representation

I would like to look at a sketch or an outline of the proof of the Gelfand-Neimark Theorem for commutative $C^{*}$ algebra's. I am doing a final year essay and I just want the major points or ideas to proving the theorem. Can you help me with this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unital case, there are three basic steps:

1. For a unital C*-algebra $A$, take $\Omega(A)$ to be the set of non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $A$. Banach-Aluoglu tells you that this is compact in the weak-$\ast$ topology.
2. For each $a\in A$, define $\hat{a} : \Omega(A)\to \mathbb{C}$ by evaluation. $\hat{a}$ is naturally continuous in the weak-$\ast$ topology, so we get a map $\Gamma : A \to C(\Omega(A))$, the space of continuous complex valued functions on $A$. This map is shown to be a homomorphism.
3. That $\Gamma$ is injective follows from the description of the spectrum of an element. That $\Gamma$ is surjective follows from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. This completes the proof.

Comment: Just a couple of things, What is Banach-Aluoglu and what is the Stone Weirstrass theorem? Also what is a *-topology?

Comment: @suunySide Did you try Googling any of these terms?

Comment: I tried searching *-topology but I am getting something not relating to topology.

Comment: Also, what about the non-unital case?

Comment: It's [weak-* topology](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=weak+star+topology).

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan What do you mean by this: define ̂ :Ω()→ℂ by evaluation?

Comment: @suunySide: I mean $\hat{a}(\tau) := \tau(a)$ for all $\tau \in \Omega(A)$.